# I want to turn on and off the internet access of a certain IP or MAC address in my network with Python

Tags: python, filtering, wifi, mac-address, disconnect

I want to turn on and off the internet access of a certain IP or MAC address in my network with Python. I researched, but mostly they are interested in getting rid of Mac filtering (Mac spoof). Is it possible to do this without using the router? Without using ARP poisoning, of course!

```
import wmi
import time
from datetime import datetime


def kontrol_zamani():
    su_an = datetime.now()
    gun_sonu = su_an.replace(hour=20, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    gun_basi = su_an.replace(hour=16, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)

    if gun_basi <= su_an <= gun_sonu:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def wifi_kapat():
    c = wmi.WMI()
    for interface in c.Win32_NetworkAdapter():
        if "Wireless" in interface.Name:
            interface.Disable()


def wifi_ac():
    c = wmi.WMI()
    for interface in c.Win32_NetworkAdapter():
        if "Wireless" in interface.Name:
            interface.Enable()


while True:
    if kontrol_zamani():
        print("Wi-Fi erişimi aktif.")
        wifi_ac()
    else:
        print("Wi-Fi erişimi kapalı.")
        wifi_kapat()

    time.sleep(60)  # Her dakika kontrol etmek için
```